# Jquery-Json returns [object,object] after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have this following ajax to call my service which fetches some records from the Database and fills it in my frontend...but i get the json:unexpected character error...can u please help me in solving this ...

```
'http://localhost/WcfService/Service1.svc/remarksList';

    var tempyear="";

    $.ajax({
                    url: urlToHandler,
                    data:JSON.stringify({oei:{"reqNo1":reqNo,"loginid":userid}}),
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType:"json",
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: function(data) {    

                    alert(data.fillRemarksListResult);
                    myData = JSON.parse(data.fillRemarksListResult, function (key, value) {
        var type;
        if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
            type = value.type;
            if (typeof type === 'string' && typeof window[type] === 'function') {
                return new (window[type])(value);
            }
        }
        return value;
    });
    alert(myData);
        $.each(data.fillRemarksListResult,function(key,val){


                alert(val.rmrkreqNo1);
                        });
                    },
                    error: function(data, status, jqXHR) {                       
                        alert('There was an error.');
                    }
                }); // end $.ajax

});
```

**Now i get this error :**

****Json.parse:unexpected character
myData=JSON.parse(data.fillRemarksListResult, function (key, value) {****

**ALSO MY AJAX CALL RETURNS** 
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] when given as alert...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are 2 ways to resolve this

**Way 1]**

Remove `dataType:"json",` from your `$.ajax` call.
Ans use `JSON.parse()`.

**Way 2]**

Keep `dataType:"json",` as it is and DO NOT use `JSON.parse()`

**WHY WHY WHY**

Here are the reasons.
As per `$.ajax()` API docs, when you specify `dataType:'json'` property, the jQuery will automatically `parse` the response from the server and pass the `parse`d JSON object to your success callback.

In this case, you are re`parse`ing the JSON object, and that is why the error is thrown.

So either do not specify `dataType:"json"` and parse the returned string
OR
Specify `dataType:"json"` and do not parse it.

Comment: Thank u so much for the crystal clear explanation dude...For a newbie lyk me dis was very helpful..!!